# Can the garbage collector in a Java container consume all cpu of the underlying node?

Tags: java, kubernetes, jvm

I have a question regarding Kubernetes. In the non-container world, I have observed that a JVM with too less of RAM allocated will consume 100% CPU on all cores, because the garbage collector does not have enough memory and thus is run more often (I guess).

In Kubernetes, I often see containers used now. Can a Java process there do the same, but causing 100% CPU usage on an entire node, and in the process, bring that node down, provided that no requests and limits are configured, and the node is overprovisioned by other pods?

Comment: in theory, `yes`

Answer (score 1):

A kubernetes pod usually runs an application as a regular container which is basically a regular process. It depends on the scheduler how to handle high load.

Nevertheless you can limit the maximum resources that can be used and you should do that:
For each container you can specify the resource limits (preventing consumption of all resources) and requests (helping with optimal scheduling) like so:

```
containers:
...
- image: ...
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 2500m
      memory: 500Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 300m
      memory: 500Mi
```

Comment: Just a reminder that this feature (be aware that it is running in a container) was introduced in Java 8u191 https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u191-relnotes.html